# cssutils parseString Fails with Media Queries. - ERROR CSSStyleDeclaration: Unexpected token

Tags: python, css, media-queries

I am unable to parse CSS strings containing media queries with `cssutils.parseString`.

In the [readme for cssutils](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils) it clearly states that media queries are supported.

How do I do this with `cssutils`?

```
>>> from cssutils import parseString
>>> css = '.font-size-24-r { font-size: 24px;\n\n@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {\n\tfont-size: 21.3px;\n}'
>>> ps = parseString(css)
ERROR   CSSStyleDeclaration: Unexpected token, ignoring upto '@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {\n\tfont-size: 21.3px;\n}'. [3:1: @media]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not the way I used `cssutils`. Rather, the issue was that I was using invalid CSS.

The error message from `cssutils` leaves a bit to be desired though it is generally indicating that the issue is in the CSS near the media query. It does not say why just `Unexpected token`. The reason is that `@media` queries cannot be nested inside of a selector block.

**Invalid CSS** - Due to nesting media queries inside of `.font-size-48-s`.

```
.font-size-48-s {
    font-size: 3em;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 45em) {
        font-size: 2.6667em
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {
        font-size: 2.4em
    }
}
```

**Valid CSS** - `cssutils.parseString` now yields the expected result.

```
.font-size-48-s { font-size: 3em }

@media only screen and (max-width: 45em) {
    .font-size-48-s { font-size: 2.6667em }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    .font-size-48-s { font-size: 2.4em }
}
```